# How to update column values ignore if exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, append

i have a pandas dataframe and a list i want to update pandas column
using that list if value already exist then ignore that row 
**(e.x)**

> ```
> my old dataframe
>   date_time           value
> 2018-11-01 00:00:02    100
> 2018-11-01 00:00:12    150
> 2018-11-01 00:00:22    56
> 2018-11-01 00:00:32    95
> 2018-11-01 00:00:42    700
>
>
> my list:
>    ["2018-11-01 00:00:02", "2018-11-01 00:00:07", "2018-11-01 00:00:12", "2018-11-01 00:00:17", "2018-11-01 00:00:22", "2018-11-01 00:00:27", "2018-11-01 00:00:32", "2018-11-01 00:00:37", "2018-11-01 00:00:42", "2018-11-01 00:00:47"]
>
> my expected output:
>    date_time           value
> 2018-11-01 00:00:02    100
> 2018-11-01 00:00:07    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:12    150
> 2018-11-01 00:00:17    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:22    56
> 2018-11-01 00:00:27    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:32    95
> 2018-11-01 00:00:37    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:42    700
> 2018-11-01 00:00:47    nan
> ```

**code :**

```
my_list = ["2018-11-01 00:00:02", "2018-11-01 00:00:07", "2018-11-01 00:00:12", "2018-11-01 00:00:17", "2018-11-01 00:00:22", "2018-11-01 00:00:27", "2018-11-01 00:00:32", "2018-11-01 00:00:37", "2018-11-01 00:00:42", "2018-11-01 00:00:47"]
df["date_time"] = pd.Series(my_list).astype(str)
```

when i execute above code it produce following output:

> ```
>    date_time           value
> 2018-11-01 00:00:02    100
> 2018-11-01 00:00:07    150
> 2018-11-01 00:00:12    56
> 2018-11-01 00:00:17    95
> 2018-11-01 00:00:22    700
> 2018-11-01 00:00:27    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:32    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:37    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:42    nan
> 2018-11-01 00:00:47    nan
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `date_time` is column create `datetimes` from `list`, create `DatetimeIndex` and use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
df = (df.set_index('date_time')
        .reindex(pd.to_datetime(my_list)
        .rename('date_time'))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
            date_time  value
0 2018-11-01 00:00:02  100.0
1 2018-11-01 00:00:07    NaN
2 2018-11-01 00:00:12  150.0
3 2018-11-01 00:00:17    NaN
4 2018-11-01 00:00:22   56.0
5 2018-11-01 00:00:27    NaN
6 2018-11-01 00:00:32   95.0
7 2018-11-01 00:00:37    NaN
8 2018-11-01 00:00:42  700.0
9 2018-11-01 00:00:47    NaN
```

Or create helper `DataFrame` and use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': pd.to_datetime(my_list)}).merge(df, how='left')
print (df)
            date_time  value
0 2018-11-01 00:00:02  100.0
1 2018-11-01 00:00:07    NaN
2 2018-11-01 00:00:12  150.0
3 2018-11-01 00:00:17    NaN
4 2018-11-01 00:00:22   56.0
5 2018-11-01 00:00:27    NaN
6 2018-11-01 00:00:32   95.0
7 2018-11-01 00:00:37    NaN
8 2018-11-01 00:00:42  700.0
9 2018-11-01 00:00:47    NaN
```

---

And if DatetimeIndex:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(my_list).rename('date_time'))
print (df)
                     value
date_time                 
2018-11-01 00:00:02  100.0
2018-11-01 00:00:07    NaN
2018-11-01 00:00:12  150.0
2018-11-01 00:00:17    NaN
2018-11-01 00:00:22   56.0
2018-11-01 00:00:27    NaN
2018-11-01 00:00:32   95.0
2018-11-01 00:00:37    NaN
2018-11-01 00:00:42  700.0
2018-11-01 00:00:47    NaN
```

Or:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': pd.to_datetime(my_list)}).join(df, on='date_time')
```

Comment: when i use this code it produce `` float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NaTType' `` and `` You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat ``

Comment: @arunkumar - Do you forget for `df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])` ? Because error means column/index or list is not converted to datetimes.